# Como simular o clique de um botão via código?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wpf

Os botões em aplicações WPF não contam com o `Button.PerformClick`. Sendo assim, como eu poderia simular o clique de um botão via código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o método [`RaiseEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) do seu [`Button`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx), como *exemplo*: criou um `BtnExemplo` e `BtnChamar` e no botão precisa chamar `BtnExemplo`:

```
private void BtnChamar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BtnExemplo.RaiseEvent(e);
}
```

Uma forma elegante poderia utilizar [método de extensão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/bb311042.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), crie uma *`classe`* com o código abaixo:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public static class MyExt
    {
        public static void PerformClick(this Button btn)
        {
            btn.RaiseEvent(new System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, btn));
        }
    }
}
```

e agora o método `PerformClick` estará disponível e pode utilizar:

```
private void BtnChamar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BtnExemplo.PerformClick();
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [UIElement.RaiseEvent Method (RoutedEventArgs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Button Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to use btn.RaiseEvent to fire button click event?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/61470273-3d43-408c-8879-5b3f1cb374e8/how-to-use-btnraiseevent-to-fire-button-click-event?forum=wpf)
- [button1.PerformClick() in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734482/button1-performclick-in-wpf)
- [O que são os Métodos de Extensão (Extension Methods) ?](http://www.macoratti.net/08/04/lnq_exm.htm)
- [C# - Métodos de Extensão](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2820/csharp-metodos-de-extensao.aspx)
- [Como implementar e chamar um método de extensão personalizado (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/bb311042.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)